# Is it possible to divide up bounty points?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have a post [that is linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191937/counting-sequential-events-and-counts-of-sequences-sql) and I feel that both people did an amazing job helping me with a solution to my query. I have used parts of each solution in my final solution; is it possible to divide my bounty to both of them?

Is something like that even a good idea?

Comment: Why do you want to divide a bounty?

Comment: The reason I want to divide the bounth is because they both did an amazing job helping me and I think it's right to reward them both since I used both of their solutions in conjunction to produce a final one

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Voting is different on meta. I simply express disagreement.

Comment: If the answers said something like "we don't want this" or "get lost", I would agree. But they're only stating the way the system currently works. (Note the question is not tagged `[feature-request]`.)

Comment: @bluefeet I am explaining. For example I offered a 250 rep bounty. On the best answer I award bounty. But then I want to award a bounty to another answer and understand thatI need 500 rep more to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you can't divide a bounty.

You *can* however, offer another bounty after awarding the current one.

Mind you, it will have to be a **higher** value bounty than before.

Comment: This is only ever possible if you're cheap and don't FULL BOUNTY questions. If you do the answer is just "sorry, StackExchange doesn't currently value your contribution enough to allow me to further incentivize your good efforts. Perhaps, you'll find more appreciation on Quora or experts-exchange"